# How can I access the DisplayName data annotation value from code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

```
public static string ProductHelper(this Product p) {
    // Need to get the DisplayName value for p.Name property
}
```

EDIT:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ProductMetadata))]
public partial class Product {
    public class ProductMetadata {
        [DisplayName("Product name")]
        public object Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Type type = typeof(Product);
DisplayNameAttribute att = (DisplayNameAttribute)type.GetProperty("Name").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).SingleOrDefault();
```

This assumes the attribute always exists. Modify for the case when it may not.

edit:
To get the value `string x = att.DisplayName;`

If Product is a base class use `Type type = p.GetType();` instead.

Comment: What if the DisplayName for the Product's Name property is provided through a MetaData class (ProductMetaData)? Please see the edited update.

Comment: Check the class for that attribute and get a reference to the specified type.
 Reflect back on the properties in that type instead.

Comment: I have property annotated in partial class, but I have 0 customAttributes, why?