# How to access the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations Display name property for a field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a viewmodel where the properties have display names. I am now making an Excel sheet with the same data in as the grid in the webpage. I am using [closed xml](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (which uses openxml) to create the Excelsheet on the server and send it to the webclient when they want to download data as Excel.
When I write the header row in Excel openxml stream I want to reuse the displayname that I already have defined. But I can't figure out what to call on.

Here is an example of the display name. ( For the example I only use two, reality there are many many more columns) :

```
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 public class DCArrival : IDCArrival
 { 
   [Display(Name = "Via Transit")]
   public String LocationType { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Currency")]
   String CurrencyISOCode { get;  }
 }
```

Then I want to use this displayname when I create the header row. Mark the pseudocode that tries to explain what I want to get hold of:

```
private MemoryStream CreateExcelFile(ICollection<DCArrival> dcArrToShow
, QueryStrInput   queryStrInput)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create an Excel Workbook
            XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
            // Add the worksheet with  data 
            IXLWorksheet ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("New Worksheet");
            // Add my data that was displayed in the html table ... 
            ws.Cell(1, 1).SetValue("Hello World");
           //Add Header row. By taking a object in the collection and figure out its
           // display name
           DCArrival firstRow = dcArrToShow.First();
           // Here comes my problem. Here is my dream up mockup code

            ws.Cell(2,1).Value = firstRow.LocationType.DisplayAttribute.GetName()
            ws.Cell(2,2).Value = firstRow.CurrencyISOCode.DisplayAttribute.GetName()
           // back to reality
           //this is how easy I can get all data from Collection
            ws.Cell(3, 1).Value = dcArrToShow.AsEnumerable();
          // All done
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            wb.SaveAs(ms);
            return ms;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string errmsg = String.Format("Failed to create Excel file: {0}",
          e.Message);
            throw new Exception(errmsg, e);
        }
```

I have looked at the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx
But I do not understand how I get a hold of it.
I understand that this is magically fixed for you when you are using normal mvc 3 html rendering. When I Google these concepts I get drowned in blogs who wants to explain basic validation in MVC 3.

Comment: see this link    [How can I access the DisplayName data annotation value from code?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485737/how-can-i-access-the-displayname-data-annotation-value-from-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could retrieve it from the model metadata:

```
ws.Cell(2.1).Value = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<DCArrival, string>(x => x.LocationType, new ViewDataDictionary<DCArrival>(firstRow)).DisplayName;
```

or write an extension method:

```
public static class ModelMetadataExtensions
{
    public static string GetName<TModel, TProperty>(this TModel model, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex)
    {
        return ModelMetadata
            .FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TProperty>(ex, new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(model))
            .DisplayName;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
ws.Cell(2.1).Value = firstRow.GetName(x => x.LocationType);
ws.Cell(2.2).Value = firstRow.GetName(x => x.CurrencyISOCode);
```

---

UPDATE:

As per a new requirement that was expressed in the comments section in order to loop through all properties and read the display attribute you could use the following:

```
var properties = typeof(DCArrival).GetProperties(); 
foreach (var property in properties) 
{
    var displayAttribute = property
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true)
        .FirstOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute;
    string displayName = property.Name;
    if (displayAttribute != null)
    {
        displayName = displayAttribute.Name;
    }

    // TODO: do something with the display name for this property
}
```

Comment: I di not understand the (firstvalue) but:
    ws.Cell(2,1).Value = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<DCArrival, string>(x => x.LocationType, new ViewDataDictionary<DCArrival>()).DisplayName;
worked fine. Thank you

Comment: @PatrikLindström, that was a typo. It must be `firstRow`. I have fixed it.

Comment: What if I would elaborate and wanted to loop over all the members of my DCArrival. I tryed this but then the DisplayName is always null.
    Type type = typeof(DCArrival);
     PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
     foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
       {
         string displayName =  
         ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<DCArrival, string>(x =>  
         property.Name, new ViewDataDictionary<DCArrival>  
        (firstRow)).DisplayName;
         ws.Cell(startRow, j++).Value = displayName;
       }

Comment: @PatrikLindström, oh no, this cannot work as you imagine. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I tryed the extension method as well. Ill stick to that one. Its more beautiful.

Comment: @PatrikLindström, look at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You guys are doing it wrong...

```
static void Main()
{

    var wb = new XLWorkbook();
    var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("People");

    var people = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person{Name = "John Doe", DOB = new DateTime(1980,1,1)},
        new Person{Name = "Jane Doe", DOB = new DateTime(1985,1,1)}
    };

    ws.FirstCell().InsertTable(people);

    ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();
    wb.SaveAs(@"C:\MyFiles\Excel Files\Sandbox.xlsx");
}

class Person
{
    [Display(Name = "Person's Name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I see I missed that documentation bit of closedxml http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Inserting%20Tables&referringTitle=Documentation 
Great now I have complete control over the CustomAttributes. Thanks