# MVC3 custom template t4 and DataAnnotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, data-annotations, t4, scaffolding

here is my model with DataAnnotations

```
[DisplayName("Title1"),Display(Name="Title2")]
public class MyClass
{
  [Display(Name = "My Class Name")]
  public string class_name { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to know how to access these DataAnnotations of class MyClass (i.e. DisplayName attibute)
in my T4 template Index.cs.t4

```
<# } #>
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "<#= viewDataType.Name   #>";
  <# if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Layout)) { #>
  Layout = "<#= Model.Layout #>";
<# } #>
}
```

instead putting viewDataType.Name I would like to have the value of DisplayName attibute of class MyClass

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[MVC Scaffolding](http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/) templates use the Visual Studio object model which is different to how the standard ASP.NET MVC templates work. The Model.ViewDataType is a Visual Studio [EnvDTE.CodeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codetype%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class and not a [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class. The EnvDTE.CodeType has an attributes property you can use to get the display name.

Here is some example code that you can use to get the display name from a CodeType. You can put this code at the end of your custom T4 template (Index.cs.t4).

```
<#+
string GetDisplayName(EnvDTE.CodeType type) {
    if (type != null) {
        foreach (var attribute in type.Attributes.OfType<EnvDTE.CodeAttribute>()) {
            if (attribute.Name == "DisplayName") {
                return attribute.Value;
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
#>
```

Then in your custom T4 template you can replace **viewDataType.Name** with a call to **GetDisplayName()**. I also removed the quotes around "**<#= viewDataType.Name #>**" since the T4 template generates quotes around the result returned from **<#= GetDisplayName(viewDataType) #>**.

```
<# var viewDataType = (EnvDTE.CodeType) Model.ViewDataType; #>
<# if(viewDataType != null) { #>
@model IEnumerable<<#= viewDataType.FullName #>>
<# } #>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = <#= GetDisplayName(viewDataType) #>;
<# if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Layout)) { #>
    Layout = "<#= Model.Layout #>";
<# } #>
}
```

If you then delete your Index.cshtml view and recreate it again with the scaffolder you should get the display name being set in the ViewBag.Title.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Title1";
}
```

Comment: this is specifically for mvc scaffolding, I believe t4 uses standard reflection though.

Comment: I agree that the question looks like it is for ASP.NET MVC and standard T4 templates but if you look at the comment made by the same user you can see they are actually talking about scaffolding.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I completely removed my answer and answering by giving you reference to the postings that are answering precisely your question *(and the answer is accepted as working in both)*:

- [How can I access the DisplayName data annotation value from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485737/how-can-i-access-the-displayname-data-annotation-value-from-code)
- [How to access the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations Display name property for a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293258/how-to-access-the-system-componentmodel-dataannotations-display-name-property-fo?lq=1)
  Hope this helps.

Comment: ok but how can I retrieve the class (or Type) from the Model in the template , with Model.ViewDataType it does not work. thanks

Comment: You know model type in advance by declaring `@model MyClass`. So you know the class of your model in advance and can use that. In case you using base class or interface, still `typeof(@Model)` should return the right type for you. Hope this clarifies

Comment: To add some context on what I would try to do  : I customize the template Index.cs.t4 (from MvcScaffolding.RazorView )and I generate the view using the package console manager (Scaffold Controller MyClass ) So the template is generic and I can't add `@model Myclass` there is already a line with @model : @model IEnumerable<<#= viewDataType.FullName #>> and  with the line  Type type = typeof(@Model) I get error : Compiling transformation: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingE54D8E877D011D6D3D777A3D7CA5B4BD.GeneratedTextTrans
formation.Model' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'. Help Thks

Comment: Updated the answer by referencing successfully answered postings. It must work for you if it worked for others. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Was it of any help for you please? Thanks